# Changed meta_key value in structures, now dashboard shows zero users

Tags: database, users, dashboard, phpmyadmin

I was trying to edit the email form field so that it accepts int values like of a phone number. I knew very less about how database values work and this is what i did: 1. Figured out that email field was "hrb_email" 2. Found that in wp_metauser hrb_email is a meta_key 3. Went to structure> and changed the meta_key from varchar to int.

Result: I cant find hrb_email in wp_metauser any more. Wordpress dashboard shows no users. Although wp_users has my user details. Also, on my website, I can see user if I manually put the URL for those users but I cant find them on the list on my website.

Please advice. Note: changing the meta_key value back to varchar does not help.

This is what meta_key looks like[image: user table][image: meta_key value changed back]

Answer (score 0):

You have destroyed a significant section of your database. Unless you have a backup you cannot get it back.

What happened when you changed the `varchar` to an `int` was that every entry not recognized as an integer was converted to `0`. You can see that in your screenshot. That is not reversible. Data was lost.

In the future:

1. Make a backup
2. Don't mess with things you don't understand. ***Take the time to
   understand*** first then mess with things.